# How to send a DELETE HTTP request with node.js?

Tags: node.js, http

I need to delete an audio file from a server, here is what I tried:

```
var payload = JSON.stringify(recordingID);

const options = {
    hostname: 'xxxxxxxxx',
    port: 443,
    path: "v3.0/recordings/" + recordingID,
    method: 'DELETE',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'X-Auth-Token': authenticationToken
    }
};

const req = https.request(options, res => {
    console.log(res);
    console.log(`statusCode: ${res.statusCode}`);

    res.on('data', d => {
        process.stdout.write(d);
    });
});
req.write(payload);
req.end();
```

But I keep on getting the following error in the console:

**408 Request Time-out
Your browser didn't send a complete request in time.**

What should I modify to get a successful response to the request?

Comment: A nit, but shouldn't the `path` start with `/`?

Comment: Thank you for pointing out my mistake. It was the problem

Answer (score 1):

It might be a problem with having a payload. DELETE requests should not have bodies. HTTP servers, clients and proxies should ideally not error but they might because DELETE bodies are sort of undefined.

Comment: In the article here [link](https://nodejs.dev/learn/making-http-requests-with-nodejs), a payload is included. Also, when I remove the payload from my HTTP request, I get a 400 Bad Request error.

Comment: Right but the article is about `POST`. `DELETE` with a body is technically incorrect. I can't say if it's Node.js that's causing the problem, it could also be a load balancer between server and client... If you get a `400 Bad Request` if you remove the body it at suggests the body _might_ be an issue.

Comment: It should be noted that the server you are talking to should not require a body for DELETE. If they do, the server does not correctly follow the HTTP spec.

Answer (score 1):

The path should start with a `/`.

```
var payload = JSON.stringify(recordingID);

const options = {
    hostname: 'xxxxxxxxx',
    port: 443,
    path: "/v3.0/recordings/" + recordingID,
    method: 'DELETE',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'X-Auth-Token': authenticationToken
    }
};

const req = https.request(options, res => {
    console.log(res);
    console.log(`statusCode: ${res.statusCode}`);

    res.on('data', d => {
        process.stdout.write(d);
    });
});
req.write(payload);
req.end();
```

I also agree that a DELETE request should not have a body, so you should investigate whether that is really supposed to be there.  Since you're putting the same value in the path, it seems likely that the body is not required.